# DialogFragment. как реализовать onDismiss()

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Есть `DialogFragment`, который запускается из `OnClickListener` в классе кастомного адаптера `ListView`:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        rowView.setClickable(true);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(clicktodraw);
       // 
       //настройка view
       //
        return rowView;
    }

    View.OnClickListener clicktodraw = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment dlg = DrawDialog.newInstance(id, newwordview.getText().toString(), translatenewwordview.getText().toString(), learnlang);
                dlg.show(fragman, "dlg1");
            }
    };
```

Закрытие диалога происходит по нажатию кнопки в нем (уже в классе диалога):

```
public View.OnClickListener drawingsavelistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        myDbHelper.save();
        dismiss();
        }
    };
```

Необходимо по закрытию диалога удалить из адаптера строку, на которую нажимали. Как это сделать?

Comment: вызываете из activity или из фрагмента?

Comment: DialogFragment dlg вызывается по нажатию кнопки, обработчик которой находится в классе кастомного адаптера listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ... implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    ...

    View.OnClickListener clicktodraw = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment dlg = DrawDialog.newInstance(id,
                newwordview.getText().toString(),
                translatenewwordview.getText().toString(), 
                learnlang);
            dlg.setOnDismissListener(CustomAdapter.this);
            dlg.show(fragman, "dlg1");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        //удаляем строку из адаптера
    }
}

public class DrawDialog extends ... {
    private DialogInterface.OnDismissListener mListener;
    public void setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (mListener !=null) {
            mListener.onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }
}
```

А вообще, вы напрасно прячете и рассеиваете логику интерфейса по разным классам. Опишите ее в activity (или в фрагменте, смотря где логичнее), все станет проще и понятнее. Т.е. адаптер, диалоги дергают методы activity, а activity управляет адаптером, показом диалога и т.д.

В вашем варианте все может стать сложнее, когда вы вдруг решите сделать другую activity (для другого разрешения, для планшета, например) с теми же фрагментами, только обновлять может потребоваться не только данные в адаптере, но и данные в других фрагментах.

Кроме того, обработчик клика для `rowView` выглядит избыточным. Для выбора элемента у listview есть `setOnItemClickListener`, который опять же можно и логичнее задать в activity (или фрагменте)...

Comment: На строке                 dlg.setOnDismissListener(MySimpleArrayAdapter.this);
cannot resolve method setOnDismissListener

Comment: @Евгений в DrawDialog реализуйте этот метод. Внимательно посмотрите на код в ответе, там все есть.

Comment: да, уже разобрался но в коде и у меня и у Вас DialogFragment dlg, а надо DrawDialog dlg, от этого и не ставился листенер.